# Customizing Graph Attributes / Object Consistency

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphviz

I have a question about selecting nodes to change certain attributes based on its name/id/title.
Even though I spent a good amount of time trying to understand the documentation on the subject ([Link](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz#customizing-graph-attributes)) I am still at a loss on how to change the color of a node based on data that is accessible pre-rendering. This is probably only because I am very new to JavaScript and D3 so I'm guessing that the solution will be simple.

In the end I would want to change color of nodes in sequence simulating a token passing through, i.e.

**first click:**
node a -> red

**second click:** node b -> red, node a -> white again

**third click:** all nodes white again

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ninji3/t5s6hucg/58/)

```
// render initial graph
d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .engine("neato")
    .dot(`digraph {a -> b}`)
    .render();

// on click, change color of 
d3.select("#graph").on("click", function () {
        console.log("click");
    /* here I would want to select manipulate a node based on its title (a or b)
       and not the ID of the group, since "id=node1" is not known before 
       rendering */
    d3.selectAll("#node1").select("ellipse").transition().attr("fill", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `d3` is that you assign data to the nodes, which you can access through a function, that then returns the new value of an attribute or style. In every case, the first argument `d` is the datum object, the second is the index in the selection, and (if I recall correctly) the third is the entire selection.

In this case, you can see the contents of `d` by just printing them to the console, since `graphviz` adds a layer of abstraction around `d3`. From there, I found that `d.parent.key` was actually the value I needed, so I could use that to access `highlightSequence`. I stored that in a list so I could easily cycle through them, if I wanted to.

```js
// render initial graph
d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
  .engine("neato")
  .dot(`digraph {a -> b}`)
  .render();

const highlightSequence = [
  { a: 'red', b: 'white' },
  { a: 'white', b: 'red' },
  { a: 'white', b: 'white' }
];
let counter = -1;

// on click, change color of 
d3.select("#graph").on("click", function() {
  console.log("click");
  counter++;
  d3.selectAll("ellipse")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      return highlightSequence[counter % highlightSequence.length][d.parent.key];
    });
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.11/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@3.0.5/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
  <div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Edit** to make it more extensible, only define colors other than white and default to that:

```js
// render initial graph
d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
  .engine("neato")
  .dot(`digraph {a -> b}`)
  .render();

const highlightSequence = [
  { a: 'red' },
  { b: 'red' },
  { }
];
let counter = -1;

// on click, change color of 
d3.select("#graph").on("click", function() {
  console.log("click");
  counter++;
  d3.selectAll("ellipse")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      return highlightSequence[counter % highlightSequence.length][d.parent.key] || 'white';
    });
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.11/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@3.0.5/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
  <div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```